# Replace multiple method calls using if statement with ternary operator in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, ternary-operator

I need to replace multiple **if** calls with ternary operators. I am currently using the if conditions to call the same method with different parameters based on the **if** condition. I am currently calling the same method with 10 if statements which is making the code very long. How can I make use of the ternary operator to overcome this?

The code is given below:

```
if (item.AdditionalData.ContainsKey(a))
    GetProjectComponent(item, Homeoffice, rx, strNLSplitter);

if (item.fields.AdditionalData.ContainsKey(b))
    GetProjectComponent(item, ProjectIndustry, rx, strNLSplitter);

if (item.fields.AdditionalData.ContainsKey(c))
    GetProjectComponent(item, ProjectCapability, rx, strNLSplitter);

if (item.fields.AdditionalData.ContainsKey(d))
    GetProjectComponent(item, ProjectTopic, rx, strNLSplitter);

if (item.fields.AdditionalData.ContainsKey(e))
    GetProjectComponent(item, ProjectTitle, rx, strNLSplitter);

if (item.fields.AdditionalData.ContainsKey(f))
    GetProjectComponent(item, ProjectCountry, rx, strNLSplitter);

if (item.fields.AdditionalData.ContainsKey(g))
    GetProjectComponent(item, ProjectState, rx, strNLSplitter);

if (item.fields.AdditionalData.ContainsKey(h))
    GetProjectComponent(item, ProjectContributors, rx, strNLSplitter);

if (item.fields.AdditionalData.ContainsKey(i))
    GetProjectComponent(item, ProjectList, rx, strNLSplitter);

if (item.fields.AdditionalData.ContainsKey(j))
    GetProjectComponent(item, ProjectArea, rx, strNLSplitter);
```

Comment: Why do you need to replace them with the ternary operator? The most important thing IMO is to make the code readable and maintainable. In some cases this can be done using the ternary operator, in other cases using an if statement might be a better solution. You can also use Dictionaries to get rid of long if/switch statements. Could you please post some code?

Comment: Can you please write your IF calls which you want to convert into ternary operators

Comment: You can write into ternary but in this also you have to write 10 ternary lines if it is ok with you then i could write the answer for you

Comment: Don't write massive ternary ifs it's awful to read and no one will be impressed. Leave it as it is. There's nothing wrong with the code you've already written.

Comment: @mjwills its a sharepoint item

Comment: *10 if statements which is making the code very long* 10 isn't long.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, how would you use a ternary operator here? I see `if` statements without an `else` or `else if` ... Code would become a big mess, probably

Comment: Looks like a job for a `Dictionary` mapping a key to a `Component`, a `switch`, or, if all else fails, a local function that extracts the common pattern. The conditional operator would be exactly the wrong thing to use here.

Comment: This is kind of [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) to me.

Comment: You could use a `Dictionary<WhateveraIs, WhateverHomeofficeIs>` and then loop through that - this would get you down to a single `if`.

Comment: @Harry I see that the first if condition is different from the rest - is this a typo or the way the code actually works?

Comment: Also, does the item contain one and only one key (e.g. `c`) or can it contain multiple ones (e.g. `a`, `b` and `c`)? I.e. will the method `GetProjectComponent` be invoked one time, or more than one?

Comment: _"I need to replace multiple if calls"_ - Do you? What kind of concern do you have about them? Speed? Number of comparisons? Code readability? It looks not like something I would feel urged to change if it runs correctly.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think the ternary operator will make it any clearer because there are 10 values to choose from and not just 2. But you could use a helper method to resolve these values. As a bonus, it can now also be called from elsewhere if needed.

Ultimately it still has the same number of if-statements, but they are now decoupled from the method call.

```
public IEnumerable<SomeType> GetSpecialValues(ItemType item)
{
    if (item.AdditionalData.ContainsKey(a)) yield return Homeoffice;
    if (item.fields.AdditionalData.ContainsKey(b)) yield return ProjectIndustry;
    if (item.fields.AdditionalData.ContainsKey(c)) yield return ProjectCapability;
    if (item.fields.AdditionalData.ContainsKey(d)) yield return ProjectTopic;
    // etc
}

// ...
foreach (var value in GetSpecialValues(item))
{
    GetProjectComponent(item, value, rx, strNLSplitter);
}
```

Comment: This seems like dancing on the head of a pin.

Comment: At least this makes it clear that GetProjectComponent() is called exactly once, which to me is already an improvement in itself.

Comment: _" is called exactly once"_ But that's not how the OP's code works. As far as I can see, it could be potentially called 0 to 10 times dependent on the conditions met.

Comment: Ultimately this code is in no way more "efficent" than what the OP already has. It's refactoring for the sake of refactoring.

Comment: @Liam I partly disagree. At least only the paramter that's actually different will be chosen according to the different cases. So it's clearer that all the other don't change. It's really not much but an improvement still , IMHO.

Comment: to quote Donald Knuth *Programmers waste enormous amounts of time thinking about, or worrying about, the speed of noncritical parts of their programs, and **these attempts at efficiency actually have a strong negative impact when debugging and maintenance** are considered. We should forget about small efficiencies, say about 97% of the time: premature optimization is the root of all evil. Yet we should not pass up our opportunities in that critical 3%.*

Comment: @Liam I absolutely agree 100% _with that quote_ - but my point was that if Peter's improvement would have been equivalent to OP's code, it would have been an improvement in _readability_ and maintainability - not at all in efficiency. But I am with you that OP's code is not really worth improving much in the first place.

Comment: Changed the answer to use IEnumerable + yield. Now it makes exactly the same calls to GetProjectComponent (0 upto 10).